# Problem in retrieve data from Firebase database in C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to retrieve data from my Firebase database. The current function I able only show the data. However after I retrieve the data I unable to pass to other variable or pass into a constructor.

**Function**

```
public Ally ReadCard() // 
{
    Ally ally = new Ally();[enter image description here][1]
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Cards").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {

        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {

        }

        DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.Result;
        var json = dataSnapshot.Child("P001-0000-0001").GetRawJsonValue();
        AllyBean card = JsonUtility.FromJson<AllyBean>(json);

        Debug.Log("Card Description : " + card.CardDescription);
        Debug.Log("Card Name : " + card.CardName);
        Debug.Log("Card Type : " + card.CardType);
        Debug.Log("Card Atk : " + card.AllyBeanProperties.Atk);
        Debug.Log("Card Hp : " + card.AllyBeanProperties.Hp);
        ally = new Ally(card.CardName, card.CardDescription, card.CardType, card.AllyBeanProperties.Atk, card.AllyBeanProperties.Hp); 

    });
    return ally;
}
```

*The purpose of this function is to allow me retrieve the data and cast it into a class object.*

**Main Program**

```
 void Start()
{
    databaseUtils = new DatabaseUtils();
    Debug.Log( "Main value : " + databaseUtils.ReadCard().CardName); //trying to retrieve data from database
}
```

**Problem**

However base on the console, the data is only shown in Debug.Log() only. The data does not appear been inserted into the constructor.

```
    Debug.Log("Card Description : " + card.CardDescription); 
    Debug.Log("Card Name : " + card.CardName);
    Debug.Log("Card Type : " + card.CardType);
    Debug.Log("Card Atk : " + card.AllyBeanProperties.Atk);
    Debug.Log("Card Hp : " + card.AllyBeanProperties.Hp);
    ally = new Ally(card.CardName, card.CardDescription, card.CardType, card.AllyBeanProperties.Atk, card.AllyBeanProperties.Hp);  // new ally object is empty
```

[Debug Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XafKw.png)

[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHNMM.png)

Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: This happens because the function returns before the `ContinueWith` part is executed. See [How to wait for a function with a task to be completed before continuing](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-wait-for-a-function-with-a-task-to-be-completed-before-continuing.625960/)

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thank you for the comment. After reading the link you provide, I manage to make it work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes**

Main file

```
DatabaseUtils databaseUtils;

async void Start()
{
    databaseUtils = new DatabaseUtils();
    Ally ally = new Ally("card name 12", "card description 12", CardType.Ally, 20, 30);
    databaseUtils.AddCard(ally);
    await databaseUtils.ReadCard();

    Debug.Log(databaseUtils.GetCard().CardName);
}
```

Read function

```
public async Task ReadCard()
{
    await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Cards").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {

        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.Result;
            var json = dataSnapshot.Child("P001-0000-0001").GetRawJsonValue();
            Ally card = JsonUtility.FromJson<Ally>(json);

            Debug.Log(card.CardDescription);
            Debug.Log(card.CardName);
            Debug.Log(card.CardType);

            Ally ally = new Ally(card.CardName, card.CardDescription, card.CardType, card.Atk, card.Hp);
            SetCard(ally);
        }

    });
}

public void SetCard(Card card)
{
    this.card = card;
}

public Card GetCard()
{
    return card;
}
```

**Note**

I receive 'async function' is not available in C# 4' error code. I update my VS and used donet4 instead

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit new to this field but I hope my answer will help regarding this question. :-)

- The following code snippet gives the simplest way to download the data from the firebase realtime database and assign them to different variables and display them within the console. I think this might gives you what you want.

Note:- When we are working with API communication kind tasks, it is better to stick with asynchronous programming.

1. Consider your data is formed within the firebase as follows.

[image: Screen shot of db]

2. Create a model class according to the DB. (This can be used for both uploading and downloading processes)

   ```
   internal class StudentDetails
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Create an asynchronous method to download the data and perform what you needed to perform.

   ```
   public class Demo                                                   
    {                                                                   
    IFirebaseClient firebaseclient2;
    int id, age = 0;
    string name, address = "";                                                        

     public async void DownloadStudentDetails()
    {
        FirebaseResponse firebaseResponse = await firebaseclient2.GetTaskAsync("Student");
        StudentDetails student = firebaseResponse.ResultAs<StudentDetails>();
        id = Convert.ToInt32(student.id.Trim());
        name = student.Name.Trim();
        address = student.Address.Trim();
        age = Convert.ToInt32(student.Age.Trim());
        Console.WriteLine(id);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(age);
        Console.WriteLine(address);
    }
   ```

   }